# I keep getting the error message ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python to extract dollar amounts from six to seven figures with dollars and comma separated. My regex tool capture both amounts but python throws a value error.
Not sure what is causing this. It works if I remove the Boolean but I have to create separate columns.

```
df3['Price'] = df3['Listings'].str.extract('(\$?\d{3}\,\d{3})|(\$?\d{1}\,\d{3}\,\d{3})',expand = True)
```

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Comment: You're assigning to one column, but you have two capture groups in the regexp.

Comment: Just put one capture group around the entire regexp, not separate groups in each alternative.

Comment: Ah that what it is. I put it in a capture group and it worked. Thanks